# Apps cannot use External Content Types defined in the Business Data Connectivity Shared Service Application metadata catalog

Tags: workflow, rest, external-content-type, packaging, external-data

My issue is getting Unauthoraized exception while accessing external data in workflow 2013 context throw REST call (HttpSend).

I read several posts suggests to create BDC model inside App package, but it doesn't solve the problem. I created propriate model and achived possibility to view external data via web interface. (External list was created manually). But still Unauthoraized exception is there:

*"Apps cannot use External Content Types defined in the Business Data Connectivity Shared Service Application metadata catalog. 
Apps should package any External Content Type definitions in a BDC model file which is packaged and deployed as part of the SharePoint App"*

Appreciate any suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of labour this issue decided to import external data direct to SharePoint internal lists using MS SQL SSIS [adapters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx).

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)